# Is there a word for a goal scored between the opponents posts (as distinct from an own goal)

Tags: football, terminology

If a player plays the ball between his own posts it is called an "own goal" and a goal is awarded to the opponents.

Is there a similar word for a goal scored correctly between the opponents posts to distinguish from an own goal?

I suppose it would usually just be called a "goal" but sometimes you might want to be specific, e.g.

e.g. "When playing against Leicester in 1976, Chris Nicholl scored 4 times. 2 own goals and 2 ____ goals."

Answer (score 4):

The term for sending the ball past the opponent's goal line into the net is *goal*.
The term for sending the ball past one's own goal line into the net is *own goal*.

You're putting the emphasis on the wrong part. Instead of distinguishing goals from own goals, you should distinguish own goals from goals - "own goal" is a term exactly for that purpose. Special occurrences of events take special names, and general events don't require specific name. Own goals are the special occurrence of goals in this scenario, and have a special name.